# C#: Max. number of COM instances that can be created to a COM class

Tags: c#, com

Can you please tell me, whether is there any limit on number of instances that can be created to a COM component in a C#  application?

because, there is a part of code in my application like this..
COMClass instance = new COMClass();

Here, if the above line gets executed for more number of times (500+ times for example,) , then I see that an error coming in my application saying that "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {<.....>} from the IClassFactory failed due to an error...."

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can´t imagine it exists hence we also load thousands of COMobjects from database without any problems.

Comment: It is only limited by available system resources consumed by that object.  Usually memory, maybe handles, if it conks out a 500 then you are using something heavy-weight.  Use a debugger or contact the owner of the COM component if you don't have source.